# anonymous function, add parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I use in my Ajax.Request my jsp. (Prototype)

Somehow I can pass extra parameters in the anonymous function onComplete?

For example,

```
function save() {
    var pars = "param1=date";
    new Ajax.Request('algo.ctr', {
        parameters: pars,
        onComplete: f,
    });
}
var f = function (e) {
    alert(e.status);
}
```

I want to use parameter e  but also other.

I do not want to use global variables.

The idea is to run multiple concurrent requests and when each one finishes doing something with an element that I put.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally you cannot "add parameters" to the Prototype function's native signature.  But you can do something like this:

```
function mySuccessFunction( a, b, c ) {
  alert( "Success!" + a + b + c ) ;
}

new Ajax.Request(url, {
  method: 'get',

  parameters: {company: 'example', limit: 12} // use an object literal
  // for parameters, not a query string

  onSuccess: function( transport ) {
    mySuccessFunction( transport, 'param1', 'param2' ) ;
  }
});
```

Note here I've passed parameters as an object literal and attached to the onSuccess event instead of the onComplete event.